# I'm having and issue with jquery ui resizable. I want to decrease and increase width in 4 equals intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Im having an issue with jquery resize.This is this is plunkr code. I want increase and decrease the width of the dropped elements in 4 equal intervals of the droppable page. I'm trying to use if else condition for getting this feature but I'm not able to do it.I'm new to jquery any help would be appreciated. http://plnkr.co/edit/E9SRGrLIfKOWiLg4BYeS?p=preview

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("ul li").each(function() {
            $(this).draggable({
                helper: "clone",
                revert: "invalid"
            });
        });
        $(".day").droppable({
            accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                var padLeft, padRight, padTotal;
                $(ui.draggable).clone().find('#drag').resizable({
                    minWidth: 60,
                    ghost: true,
                    handles: 'e',
                    resize: function(event, ui) {
                        debugger;
                        ui.size.width = ui.size.width + 200;
                        if (ui.size.width > 800) {
                            ui.size.width = 800;
                        }
                        if (ui.size.height < 90) {
                            ui.size.height = 90;
                        }
                        if (ui.size.width < 400 && ui.size.width > 204) {
                            ui.size.width = 200;
                        }
                    },
                    start: function(event, ui) {},
                    stop: function(event, ui) {}
                }).appendTo(this);
            }
        }).sortable({
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems looking at the code that you have a width of `200px` and height of `90px` and you want to be able to resize their width after they are dropped but only in multiples of `200` until they reach a max width of `800`. To do that you can use the `minWidth`, `maxWidth` and `grid` options.

```
$(ui.draggable).clone().find('#drag').resizable({
    minWidth: 200,
    maxWidth: 800,
    ghost: true,
    handles: 'e',
    grid: [200, 90],
    start: function(event, ui) {
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
    }
});
```

The max and min are probably obvious but you can read more about the `grid` option here:

http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-grid

> Snaps the resizing element to a grid, every x and y pixels. Array
>   values: [ x, y ].

Also I saw you have multiple divs with the same id of `drag` in your HTML. IDs should be unique just for future reference. Instead give them unique IDs and a common class and use that class in your `find`.

HTML:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="input">
        <div style="background-color:darksalmon" class="draggableItem" id="drag1">Input</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div style="background-color:moccasin;" class="draggableItem" id="drag2">Textarea</div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <div style="background-color:saddlebrown;" class="draggableItem" id="drag3">Dropdown</div>
    </li>
    <li class="checkbox">
        <div style="background-color:plum" class="draggableItem" id="drag4">checkbox</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(ui.draggable).clone().find('.draggableItem').resizable({
```

Comment: is there any way to divide the droppable page to 4 equal columns to resize the width to each column every time we try to resize the width of dropped element.

Comment: I am not sure I understand exactly what you want.

Comment: https://www.formstack.com/demo this site has the feature I'm trying to implement something like that. we have an option called setting columns in to 4 ,3 ,2 ,1. If we set 4 colums the page has 4 variable widths for the drooped elements. If it is set to 3 it has 3 variable heights.